# Removing symbols from object file on windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, linker, object-files

Is there any way to remove(or make local) symbols in an object file? I'm looking for something like `objcopy --keep-global-symbol` on linux.

Or maybe there is a way to tell linker which symbols should be hidden? I found this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h.aspx which describes .Def files and my impression from the reading is that I can use these files not only for dll's but also for static libraries. Is this true?

I need this, because I link with 2 libraries A and B which export the same symbols. A is linked dynamically and B is linked statically. If a symbols is exported both by A and B I want my app to use symbol from A, plus I want to use some symbols from B (which are only in B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install one of the Mingw GCC ports, e.g. [mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php),
then you will also get the ports of `binutils` for Windows PE binaries and you will be able to use
the familar `objcopy --keep-global-symbol`.

Find it in the `bin` directory of your chosen installation, e.g. `C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin`

**However...**

You may well have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here,
because the linker will resolve a symbol from the first library in the input sequence
that defines it and ignore definitions in later libraries; so you may be able to
give preference to the definitions from the DLL just by linking it before the static
library. An illustration:

**foo_static.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    puts("foo_static");
}
```

**bar_static.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(void)
{
    puts("bar_static");
}
```

**foo_dynamic.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void foo(void)
{
    puts("foo_dynamic");
}
```

**gum_dynamic.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void gum(void)
{
    puts("gum_dynamic");
}
```

Compile the `*_static.c` source files and archive the object files in a static library `static.lib`:

```
>cl -c *_static.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

bar_static.c
foo_static.c
Generating Code...

>lib -out:static.lib *_static.obj
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Compile the `*_dynamic.c` source files and link the object files in a DLL `dynamic.dll`:

```
>cl -c *_dynamic.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

foo_dynamic.c
gum_dynamic.c
Generating Code...

>link -dll -out:dynamic.dll *_dynamic.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Creating library dynamic.lib and object dynamic.exp
```

Notice that function `foo` is defined (differently) in `static.lib` and `dynamic.dll`.
`bar` is defined only in `static.lib`. `gum` is defined only in `dynamic.dll`

Here is a program source that calls `foo`, `bar` and `gum`:

**main.c**

```
extern void foo();
extern void bar();
extern void gum();

int main()
{
    foo();
    bar();
    gum();
    return 0;
}
```

which we compile:

```
>cl -c main.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.c
```

Then we link a program `prog` like this:

```
>link -out:prog.exe main.obj static.lib dynamic.lib
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

with `static.lib` first. The program outputs:

```
>prog.exe
foo_static
bar_static
gum_dynamic
```

So `foo` was resolved from `static.lib` and the definition from
`dynamic.dll` was ignored.

Now lets relink with the order of the libraries reversed, and run `prog` again:

```
>link -out:prog.exe main.obj dynamic.lib static.lib
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


>prog.exe
foo_dynamic
bar_static
gum_dynamic
```

This time, `foo` was resolved from `dynamic.dll` and the definition from `static.lib`
was ignored.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, however ideally I would rather not install any additional programs. Do you happen to know the answer to the question I just added in the edit (about .Def files)?

Comment: @Igor No, a `.def` file can only be used, by the linker, in the linkage of a program or DLL. Not a static
library, because a static library, unlike a program or DLL, isn't produced by the linker (`link`),
it's produced just by the archiver (`lib`). See [static-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info).
However my extended answer might help.

Comment: Thank you, for the explanation, that's indeed solves my issue. Do I understand correctly (from the link you posted) that this behaviour depends on the linker? Would that give the same results on linux (using GNUs ld)?

Comment: @Igor Yes, this behaviour will be the same with the GNU/Linux toolchain